# How can I direct all pages except one to HTTPS in an htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, laravel-4

Currently I am redirecting all pages to https using the following htaccess directive:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

But I have one page, `http://foo.bar/baz` which needs to be accessed http-only. Using an htaccess directive, how can I redirect to https on all pages except this one, where users are forced to http?

Edit: I should have mentioned that this is a Laravel 4 application, and I currently also have the following rules to handle the front-controller

```
# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a negative regex pattern in `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/baz[/?\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /baz[/?\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php - [L,NC]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301,NE]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: Sorry, can you explain the logic here?

Comment: Hmm. This doesn't seem to work for me. /baz still redirects https.

Comment: I added some information about the application being laravel and the rules that come with it. Could you look at it and get back to me?

Comment: Ah I see so you had other rules. I've provided you full .htaccess that should work for you. Do completely clear your browser cache.

Comment: Okay, so this allows me to view baz over http, but it doesn't force http on baz. Any chance I can force it?

Answer (score 1):

A negative lookahead works especifically for these cases when you want one or more exceptions:

```
RewriteRule ^(?!baz)(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L]
```

This basically says, redirect everything except baz.

SideNote: Remember ".htaccess" is not some sort of rewrites depot for Apache, if you have access to the config in the virtualhost, make sure to add these rewrites in there. htaccess adds overhead and complexity.